# Combining planar RGB images into lossless video with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, image, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a series of images already in memory. The images are RGB, but planar, i.e. non-interleaved. I wish to use ffmpeg to losslessly compress these into a video.

Currently I have this (note: i have excluded error checking and cleanup):

```
av_register_all();

AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264rgb");

AVCodecContext* context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
context->width = width;
context->height = paddedHeight;//height padded to a multiple of 8
context->time_base = AVRational { 1,25 };
context->gop_size = 10;
context->max_b_frames = 1;
context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
av_opt_set(context->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(context->priv_data, "crf", 0, 0);//lossless

avcodec_open2(context, codec, NULL);

AVFrame* avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
for (int i = 0; i < AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS; i++) {
    avFrame->data[i] = NULL;
}
avFrame->data[0] = new uint8_t[width*paddedHeight];
avFrame->data[1] = new uint8_t[width*paddedHeight];
avFrame->data[2] = new uint8_t[width*paddedHeight];

AVFormatContext* outputContext;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outputContext, NULL, NULL, "filename.webm");

AVStream* outputStream = avformat_new_stream(outputContext, codec);
outputStream->codecpar->width = width;
outputStream->codecpar->height = paddedHeight;
outputStream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP;
outputStream->time_base = AVRational { 1,25 };

outputContext->video_codec = codec;
avio_open2(&outputContext->pb, "filepath\filename.webm", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, NULL);//obviously a real filepath is being used

avformat_write_header(outputContext, NULL);

uint8_t* R, G, B;
while(GetNextImageChannels(&R, &G, &B)){
    memcpy(R, avFrame->data[0], width * height * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(G, avFrame->data[1], width * height * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(B, avFrame->data[2], width * height * sizeof(uint8_t));

    avcodec_send_frame(context, avFrame);

    AVPacket encodedPacket;
    avcodec_receive_packet(context, &encodedPacket);
    av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &encodedPacket);
}

av_write_trailer(outputContext);
```

This is currently failing at `avformat_write_header`, giving me an error code of -22, which I believe means invalid arguments of some sort?

I've tried using `filename.mkv` but that fails at `avformat_alloc_output_context2` with error code -22

I've tried using the `AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP` format, but that fails at `avcodec_open2` with error code -22 as well.

I've found various resources on ffmpeg out there, but most of them are using the commandline application. The few that aren't are very generic, and mostly outdated(using deprecated functions), and are usually converting from one video format to another, and none of them are dealing with planar images.

**If you could please help me out with what I'm getting wrong?**

EDIT: fixed a typo in the array index

Answer (score 0):

Finally had time to install & build it.
So here we go:

1) Activate debug logging. It is very useful.

```
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
```

Do you call registration?

```
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();
```

2) Looks like the codec that you want to use does not support planar RGB formats.
For me AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP failes with "invalid arguments" error.
You need to specify some packed RGB format (AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 will do), and convert your separate color channels into a single array.

```
avFrame->data[0] = new uint8_t[3*width*paddedHeight];
. . .
uint8_t* R, G, B;
uint8_t* row = avFrame->data[0];
while(GetNextImageChannels(&R, &G, &B)){
    for(int iy=0; iy<height; ++iy){
        for(int ix=0; ix<width; ++ix){
            row[3*ix+0] = R[ix];
            row[3*ix+1] = G[ix];
            row[3*ix+2] = B[ix];
        }
        R += width;
        G += width;
        B += width;
        row += 3*width;
    }
```

3) WebM does not support h264. So it's back to mkv.
You need to create video stream:

```
AVFormatContext* outputContext;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outputContext, NULL, "h264", "filename.mkv");
AVStream* video_stream = avformat_new_stream(outputContext, codec);
video_stream->codec = c;
avio_open(&outputContext->pb, "filename.mkv", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
avformat_write_header(outputContext, NULL);
```

Comment: Oh goodness, yes, that is a typo. However I've just fixed it up and i'm getting exactly the same results as before (tried with both formats)

Comment: What about padding?

Comment: I've just tried, padding out to 8, 16 and 32 for both height and width. unfortunately it hasn't worked

Comment: What about packed RGB?

Comment: Remember it's erroring before it even reaches the loop. I believe it's something to do with the way i'm setting the whole thing up, like maybe I've missed some setting, or I'm not linking two constructs together properly. 

Just to confirm it's not the number of data buffers, I tried this anyway and it didn't work

Comment: Lack of detailed code samples does make it more complicated than it should be…

Comment: I agree! 

Thanks for this, I'll try it soon and get back to you~

Comment: I tried this and it at least got the part's you've covered working. (Although I'm going to have to rewrite the planar->interleaved conversion to use AVX instructions because I have a speed constraint)

I managed to make some more progress on my own after that and am now stuck on the file not being finalised properly. it's successfully calling `av_write_trailer`, but the file is left in an open state and cannot be played by applications.